# How to link an external css file in a view.xhtml?

Tags: orbeon

I have the following trivial `hello.xhtml` view which links an external stylesheet `view.css`.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="view.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <span class="warning">Hello world!</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is the recommended way to configure the controller? The two approaches below do not work in my environment.

#### controller, files element with wildcards - not working

```
<controller xmlns="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/controller">
    <page path="/hello-world/hello" view="hello.xhtml"/>
    <files path="*.css" />
</controller>
```

The following error is reported in `orbeon.log`:

```
Dangling meta character '*' near index 0                                                                              |
|*css
```

#### controller, files element with specific path - not working

```
<controller xmlns="http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/controller">
    <page path="/hello-world/hello" view="hello.xhtml"/>
    <files path="/hello-world/view.css" />
</controller>
```

Tomcat access logs reports a 404 error

```
127.0.0.1 - - [...] "GET /orbeon/hello-world/view.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of the `path` attribute is a regexp, so you'll want to have something like:

```
<files path=".+\..css"/>
```

But usually, this isn't necessary, as if you're placing files inside an "app" (like `apps/xforms-hello`), then the [root page flow](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/blob/master/src/resources/page-flow.xml) applies, and it already defines that `*.css` should be served as files.